# Alias to 'cd' Command with Subshell Not Working as Expected

Tags: bash, alias, subshell

I just learned about aliases in bash.  I created one like so:

`alias="cd $directory"`

where `$directory` is from use input.  In another shell script, I can launch a subshell like so:

`( bash )`

which brings me to the subshell, where, if I run `cd`, I go to the alias, `cd $directory`. This is great and it seems to be working as expected.

What I'm looking for is for when the subshell is launched, the cd happens automatically, so I tried:

`( bash | cd )`

thinking it would launch the subshell and cd to the user-entered `$directory`but it's not working.  How can I go about getting this to work?  I also tried `( bash -c cd)` to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. It has nothing to do with programming - it's an operating system question. As such, it should be asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com) instead; SO is for programming related questions and answers. Please take a few minutes to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for info on what questions are (and are not) suitable here. Thanks. :)

Comment: Really?  I thought bash scripting would be considered programming...  There are many other bash related question on SO...

Comment: Bash scripting would be. Aliases are basic bash operations, not scripting. (Asking how to do something in a bash script is on-topic; asking how to change directories or list files in a bash shell isn't. This question falls into the latter category, IMO.)

Comment: Fair enough.  My apologies.  I will ask in SU next time.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `( bash | cd )` doesn't work is that each command in a pipeline is run in a separate subshell, so `( bash | cd )` is essentially equivalent to `( ( bash ) | ( cd ) )` (except that the latter launches even *more* subshells, of course). Instead, you should be able to write:

```
( cd ; bash )
```

(which runs `cd` *before* running `bash`) since `bash` will inherit a copy of the execution environment of the subshell it was launched from.

By the way — are you sure you want to create `cd` as an alias this way? That seems error-prone and confusing to me. I think it would be better to create a shell function that `cd`s to the user-specified directory:

```
function cd_user () { cd "$directory" ; }

( cd_user ; bash )
```

Comment: Yah, you're right; I don't want to create `cd` as an alias this way.  I am just using it as an example. I would do something like `cd_udir` (like you point out).  Your answer is very informative, too, by the way; thank you.  Trying it now.

Comment: Your answer did solve my problem.  Thanks.  But I took your other recommendation and tried it and it didn't work.  Could you look at my code and give me a hand with the function?  I should have mentioned that the subshell is being called in another function within the script so I'm getting an error: `mmf.sh: line 79: cd_udir: command not found`

Comment: @nicorellius: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to call one function from another. :-/

Comment: you're right.  I double checked my function and I had an typo in there.  Thanks again for your help and patience ;-)