# Aliases are not executed in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

In my bashrc file I have n number of alias. But, If I execute via shell script, 
it will not give expected output. Why it will be like this. Is there any way to 
solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: alias are not exported to sub-shells

Comment: Is there any way to export the alias to sub shells

Comment: You need to source in the same alias file in your script like `source ~/.alias`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alias to 'cd' Command with Subshell Not Working as Expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780624/alias-to-cd-command-with-subshell-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Aliases are also not expanded in non-interactive shells by default.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases (as set using `alias name=value`) are *only* used in an interactive context, i. e. when the user types something on the command line.  They are *never* executed by a script (unless a non-interactive shell is explicitly tweaked to do this using the `shopt -s expand_aliases`):

```
#!/bin/bash
alias ttt=date
ttt  # will fail!
```

Sourcing a configuration script which defines aliases will not change anything about this.  Scripts simply will not execute aliases.

To achieve what you want, rewrite your aliases as shell functions:

```
#!/bin/bash
ttt() {
  date
}
ttt  # will succeed!
```

Shell functions can replace aliases completely but there are some more things to know and consider:

1. You can even export shell functions so that child shells also have them.  Use `export -f ttt` for this.
2. Shell functions can override other commands so they can interfere in the behaviour of scripts (unlike aliases which are *never* executed in scripts).  Keep this in mind in case you plan to override things like `cd` or `ls`.
3. An overridden built-in of the shell (e. g. `cd`) can still be reached by calling it as `builtin cd /my/direc/tory`.
4. Argument handling is quite different from aliases (and much more powerful).

Comment: It's a little strong to say aliases are *never* expanded in scripts; you can enable them with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: Yeah, but who does?  But you are right of course.  I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Nobody, because functions are the better idea :)